# Symfony 2 - How to allow a entities variable which is an object of another entity to be null?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

So lets say I have an Entity-Class `Travel`:

```
<?php

namespace Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity;

class Travel {

     ...

    /**
     *
     * @var \Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity\MilageAllowance
     */
    private $milageAllowance;

    ...

    /**
     * Set milageAllowance
     *
     * @param \Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity\MilageAllowance $milageAllowance         
     *
     * @return Travel
     */
    public function setMilageAllowance(\Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity\MilageAllowance $milageAllowance = null) {
        $this->milageAllowance = $milageAllowance;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get milageAllowance
     *
     * @return \Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity\MilageAllowance
     */
    public function getMilageAllowance() {
        return $this->milageAllowance;
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is the Doctrine .yml-file:

```
# src/TravelCostsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Travel.orm.yml
Pec\Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Entity\Travel:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Pec\Bundle\TravelCostsBundle\Repository\TravelRepository
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: {strategy: AUTO}
  ...
  oneToOne:
    milageAllowance:
      targetEntity: MilageAllowance
      mappedBy: travel
  fields:
    ...
```

The Application is connected with a database using Doctrine. I validate the Entities with a `validation.yml`-file and have a Form to create an Entity of Type `Travel` with fields for the variables of the `milageAllowance`-Entity.

I want that it is optional to fill the fields so...

- if the fields are empty `$milageAllowance` stays `NULL` and (far more important) NO entry in the database will be created

  - if the fields are filled an entry in the database will be created.

Is that even possible with a oneToOne-relation?

How to validate that the Entity `Travel` can have just 1 or no `milageAllowance`?

I appreciate your help... Please ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: How would you want to accomplish this? Adding multiple millageAllowance  in the same form and when submit, attach this millageAllowance to the travel entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Stas Parshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619961/stas-parshin) which gives me one part of the answer. So set `nullable: true` in the `orm` file:

`Travel.orm.yml`:

```
Projekt\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Travel:
  oneToOne:
    milageAllowance:
      targetEntity: MilageAllowance
      mappedBy: travel
      JoinColumn:
        nullable: true
```

Inside the `TravelType` class set the added `ReceiptType` form to `'required' => false`:

```
class TravelType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('milageAllowance', MilageAllowanceType::class, array(
                'required'      => false,
            //Are all fields of milageAllowance empty => $travel->milageAllowance == NULL
                ...
        ))
```

Like it is commented if all fields are of `ReceiptType` left blank the property `$travel->milageAllowance == NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your OneToOne relation optional by setting JoinColumn(nullable=true)

Using YML notation it would look like this:

```
    ...
  oneToOne:
    milageAllowance:
      targetEntity: MilageAllowance
      mappedBy: travel
  JoinColumn
    nullable: true 
  fields:
    ...
```

See this page for more info:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I have a form with fields for the `milageAllowance` and validation rules for `milageAllowance` inside the `validation.yml`. If I submit the basic form will the validation just be wrong or do I have to explicitly tell Symfony somewhere the fields can stay empty?

Comment: If you had assertions like NotBlank or NotNull on that field - I supposed you should remove them to make things work, if not - all should be fine

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I read the article [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_collections.html) which also does not include validation of Entities for an arbitrary number of Entity objects. But i think this is more or less messy because the simple validation possibilities in Symfony are there to use them. Is there a way to add validation constraints which get used just when I want the Entitity object to get a value? Later on I maybe will add some code in my question to show more exactly what I mean...